# Call JavaScript function from Drupal module?

Tags: drupal

Im a Drupal themer and im struggling to modify a module in the way that I need. When something happens I need to run a very simple bit of JavaScript. Ive found the part of the module responsable and the following works:

```
if (something = something else) {
  return array(
            '#commands' => array(

      // Hacky by works 
        ajax_command_append('body', 
        '<script>
            alert("Custom Js");
        </script>'),

    ),
  );
}
else {
  // Do something else 
}
```

However it would be better to call a function that was somewhere else as other modules will want to call it. How can I call a function from another module from within this statement?

Comment: Some useful stuff here if working with AJAX: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18867/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-function-when-a-drupal-ajax-call-is-complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it inline, like this

**Edit**

In my first answer I forgot to wrap the javascript in `jQuery(document).ready(function() {})`

module

```
if (something = something else) {

    // Inline fixed
    drupal_add_js("jQuery(document).ready(function() { alert('Script inline!'); });", "type" => "inline");        

    // From file
    drupal_add_js("myscript.js", "file");

  return array(
    '#commands' => array(
    ),
  );
}
else {
  // Do something else 
}
```

myscript.js

```
(function() {
    alert('Script from file!');
});

// or with jQuery
(function($) {
    // Do something with $
})(jQuery);
```

If you want the javascript code to be in on its own file, do it like that (taken from the examples)

Check out the examples in the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

More information on adding javascript to your modules/themes

[Adding Javascript to your theme or module](https://www.drupal.org/node/304255)

[Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722)

**Edit 2**

You can call a javascript function from a module. I would do it like this :

- Create a new module that just inject a javascript code. This module should have a lesser weight than any other module so it executes before any of them.
- Then call it from any module using `Drupal.settings`.

Assuming that you created the module, you should save your javascript function into `Drupal.settings`

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.settings.exampleModule = {
    myFunction : function () {
        alert('My example function!');
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

This will inject that code into `settings` and will be available to any module which needs to access it.

Your module

```
if (something = something else) {

    // Inline fixed
    drupal_add_js("(function($) { Drupal.settings.exampleModule.myFunction(); })(jQuery);", "type" => "inline"); 

}
else {
  // Do something else 
}
```

That's how I would do it. Now, if you need to use the ajax framework you should do something like this (try it, I've never used this framework before, so I'm guessing)

```
return array(
    '#commands' => array(

        // Hacky by works 
        ajax_command_append('body', "(function($) { Drupal.settings.exampleModule.myFunction(); })(jQuery);"),

    ),
);
```

Comment: That didnt work for me but ive altered my question anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to call a function from within a javascript file in an existing module?

Comment: See my edit. It is possible, I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: I think that ajax_command_append from your last example requires script tags. While this may be workable is the only way to access the existing javascript to inject other javascript into the page? This seems very hacky to me.

Comment: I'm not aware of another way, which doesn't mean it doesn't exist. If you check the documentation for [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) you can see under `$data` parameters there is a `setting` parameter which lets you inject your own javascript into `Drupal.settings`. This means is provided by Drupal people, so I don't it is hacky at all.